# Kivy, how to disable console

Tags: python, kivy

I'm coding some software with python and kivy and want to disable the command window, that opens up in window side by side with the kivy app.

I entered that command in the command window to call the python prog:

```
python main.py -m console
```

From now on, I can click once at any kivy widget on the bottom side of my app. Then there is that console showing in the picture below. I can disable it by pressing STRG+E twice (activate, then deactivate).

The bad thing, this console part is there with every program start out of eclipse, direct call by python main.py or also in the compiled version, compiled with pyinstaller.

I tried to reinstall whole python on my system, but it doesn't work.

[image: kivy console]

How can I disable this console thingy?

Comment: Please, share your code, it's hard to tell what exactly is going on

Comment: The code is too long to post here and I'm relatively shure, that the code has nothing to do with the issue itself. There was no change in the code, where the console problem started to occur.

Comment: Then what is the issue? Clear up your question. Post as much code as needed to still reproduce the problem. To provide a good answer, people need to see the issue themselves

Comment: The problem is, that after calling the main.py with that command "python main.py -m console" this console is there at every start. First it is not visible and opens up after clicking around in that lower area.
Pressing CRTL+E twice enables and disables the console and everything is fine tue the next start of the main.py.
I'm searching for an command that disables this "python main.py -m console" again or someting to reset all kivy settings back to default.

Answer (score 3):

If you're packaging your app with PyInstaller, you should take a look at the [`--noconsole`](http://pyinstaller.readthedocs.io/en/stable/man/pyinstaller.html?highlight=noconsole#windows-and-mac-os-x-specific-options) command line option. It should get rid of the console in Windows and OS X:

> Windows and Mac OS X: do not provide a console window for standard i/o. On Mac OS X this also triggers building an OS X .app bundle. This option is ignored in *NIX systems.

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
if sys.platform=="win32":
    import ctypes
    ctypes.windll.user32.ShowWindow( ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetConsoleWindow(), 0 )
```